# Converting a flask app to an application factory pattern screws up all imports

Tags: python, flask

So i've been building a flask app just using an `app.py` file and running it.
It has quite a big app now and i'm now just trying to convert it into an application factory because I need to use SQLAlchemy in my Celery tasks.

here is my **init**.py in my app folder

```
def create_app():
    load_dotenv(".env")
    app = Flask(__name__)

    app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:///data.db"
    app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False
    app.config["PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS"] = True
    app.config["BROKER_URL"] = os.getenv("REDIS_BACKEND_BROKER")
    app.config["CELERY_BROKER_URL"] = os.getenv("REDIS_BACKEND_BROKER")
    app.config["CELERY_IMPORTS"] = "celery_tasks"
    app.secret_key = os.getenv("SECRET_KEY")

    CORS(app)
    api = Api(app)
    jwt = JWTManager(app)

    db.init_app(app)
    ma.init_app(app)
    celery.init_app(app)

    @app.before_first_request
    def create_tables():
        db.create_all()

    @jwt.invalid_token_loader
    def invalid_token_callback(self):
        return {"message": "invalid"}, 401

    with app.app_context():

        from .resources.auth import Auth, CheckUser
        from .resources.period import Period
        from .resources.project import Project
        from .resources.session import Session

        api.add_resource(Auth, "/auth")
        api.add_resource(CheckUser, "/check")
        api.add_resource(Project, "/createproject")
        api.add_resource(Period, "/createperiod")
        api.add_resource(Session, "/createsession")
        return app
```

The problem is that all the resources that being imported breaks because they can no longer import based on modules either.

For example resources.period also imports SQLAlchemy models and Masrhmallow schemas

**resources/period.py**

```
#THESE ARE NO LONGER IMPORTED SUCCESSFULLY

from models.project import ProjectModel
from schemas.task import TaskSchema
from schemas.period import PeriodSchema
```

[Here is my file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzRsO.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're importing from `resources/period.py` using relative imports, you need to go up a level:

```
from ..models.project import ProjectModel
from ..schemas.task import TaskSchema
from ..schemas.period import PeriodSchema
```

Comment: Yes, they are imported like so. Otherwise, I wouldn't have been able to import them originally using just app.py and not an application factory

Comment: Ah, I just noticed that the imports that were failing were from `resources/period.py` rather than `app.py`. I've amended by answer now.

Comment: What Futureflo said would also work as long as your app is in the PYTHONPATH.

Answer (score 2):

This is an awesome tutorial by Miguel Grinberg where he refactores a complete application like you want it, too:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NH-8oLHUyDc&t=2934s

Did you try to make an "absolute" import like:

```
from app.models.project import ProjectModel
```